# CSS + JS files not found (404) when using url parameters in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I create a dashboard page that display some graphs.

The page refresh the graph data every one hour automatically.

the URL to the page is:

```
http://localhost/dashboard
```

I wan't to let the user option to declare the idle time between one refresh to another as 
part of the URL

something like:

```
http://localhost/dashboard/refresh/60
```

or

```
http://localhost/dashboard/?refresh=60
```

I choose to start with the first URL option:

I fix the urls.py file like that:

```
url(r'^dashboard/refresh/(?P<refresh>\w+)$', 'management.static_views.dashboard'),
```

and the static_views.py like this:

```
def dashboard(request,refresh=None):

"""  
Dispaly the dashboard for
"""
if refresh:
        print refresh
return render_to_response('dashboard.html')
```

Everything work fine, and I get the refresh parameter.
The problem start when the page is loading and try to GET the css and JS files from the server.

I got this Error in chrome logs:

```
GET http://localhost/dashboard/css/dashboard.css 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

and in Django server I see this log:

```
GET /dashboard/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1703
```

In the html file the link tag to the css look like this:

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dashboard.css"/>
```

Why the css loaded fine when I **don't** using the refresh parameter and **not loaded** when i using him ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Django that `dashboard.css` is a static file, otherwise it's loading relative to the current url.

```
# template file
{% load staticfiles %}
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/dashboard.css" %}"/>
```